# python dict flatten nested dict values to create new key value pair in numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Hi I have data in below structure where I have a map of key as label and value as array of array  and I want to flatten the values and dynamically add index to the key to create a new row like below. I can iterate over each key-value pain and create new dict and add these values to it and get the expected result but its slow. I have around 50M values in array, is there a faster approach in numpy/pandas?

This is what I have

```
{'user_feature': 
array([
[ 1.33677050e-02, -1.45685431e-02], 
[-2.30765194e-02, 0.00000000e+00],
[0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],  
[1.16669689e-04,  1.33677050e-02]]), 
'sequence_service_id_list': 
array([y
[215., 215., 215., ..., 554., 215., 215.],
[215., 215., 215., ..., 215., 215., 215.],
[215., 215., 554., ..., 215., 215., 215.], 
'target_label': 
array([
1., 
1., 
1., ..., 1., 1., 1.])}
```

Expected:

```
{'user_feature_1': [ 1.33677050e-02, -1.45685431e-02], 
'user_feature_2': [-2.30765194e-02, 0.00000000e+00],
'user_feature_3': [0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
'sequence_service_id_list_1': [215., 215., 215., ..., 554., 215., 215.],
'sequence_service_id_list_2': [215., 215., 215., ..., 215., 215., 215.],
'sequence_service_id_list_3': [215., 215., 554., ..., 215., 215., 215.], 
'target_label_1': 1., 
'target_label_2': 1., 
'target_label_3': 1., 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that over just indexing the arrays?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't do anything special with `dicts`.  Those are python objects.  `items` and `values` can convert the dict to lists (and tuples), but otherwise `dict` are referenced by key.

Comment: When breaking arrays up like this, it may help to first use `arr.tolist()` to convert the array to (nested) list.   Iteration on lists is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a vectorized solution to create the dict you want, but a way to access the required rows using keys that follow the new format.

Let's define a class to wrap this input dictionary. When you try to get a key from an object of this class, the `__getitem__` method is invoked, where the key is parsed into its "original key" and "index" components, and the appropriate row of the appropriate value is returned.

```
class CustomDict:
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        self.__data = input_dict

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        orig_key, elem_index = key.rsplit("_", 1)
        return self.__data[orig_key][int(elem_index)-1]
```

Let's test this:

```
array = np.array

inp_dict = {'user_feature': array([[ 1.33677050e-02, -1.45685431e-02], 
                                   [-2.30765194e-02, 0.00000000e+00],
                                   [0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],  
                                   [1.16669689e-04,  1.33677050e-02]]), 
            'sequence_service_id_list': array([[215., 215., 215., 554., 215., 215.],
                                               [215., 215., 215., 215., 215., 215.],
                                               [215., 215., 554., 215., 215., 215.]]), 
            'target_label': array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])}

cus_dict = CustomDict(inp_dict)

print(cus_dict['user_feature_1'])
# [ 0.01336771 -0.01456854]

print(cus_dict['user_feature_2'])
# [-0.02307652  0.        ]

print(cus_dict['user_feature_3'])
# [0. 0.]
```

Since you never iterate over anything, and splitting the key is a simple, quick operation that happens at the time of access, this will be much faster than creating a new dictionary.

You can also implement a similar `__setitem__` method to set elements of the original dictionary:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    orig_key, elem_index = key.rsplit("_", 1)
    self.__data[orig_key][elem_index] = value
```

Comment: Awesome, this is smart, this exactly what I was looking for. Bruteforce approach of iterating through it was bad.